Problems installing libdb++-dev on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I am trying to install the libdb++-dev using:
sudo apt install libdb++-dev, however this does not seem to work and it keeps generating the following error: See screenshot
The given solution in the linked post does not work as there are no packages listed as 'broken' when using grep.
Even when trying to install using the following link, it does not download the package: https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/noble/main/base/libdb%2B%2B-dev
I feel like it's not necessarily the package manager that is broken, but more like the package itself is broken.
It does not seem to work. My download does not start.
How can I get this resolved?
Thanks in advance

This question is similar to: E:Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
